# Android, OpenCV: Detect color & Draw Contours

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, mask, contour

How do i draw contours on only black object, and filling everything else in the background white?
My code currently is able to draw contours on an image:

```
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("byteArray"),0,getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("byteArray").length);
srcMat= new Mat();
Utils.bitmapToMat(b,srcMat);

Mat gray = new Mat();
Imgproc.cvtColor(srcMat, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);

Imgproc.Canny(gray, gray, 20, 20*3, 3, true);
List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();
Mat hierarchy = new Mat();

Imgproc.findContours(gray,contours,hierarchy,Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
for (int contourIdx = 0; contourIdx < contours.size(); contourIdx++) {
    Imgproc.drawContours(srcMat, contours, contourIdx, new Scalar(0, 0, 255), -1);
}

Utils.matToBitmap(gray, b);
imgR.setImageBitmap(b);
```

Comment: You want to create mask of the image by creating a contour or what other kind of contour you talking about here.
Please provide output that you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create and apply mask, like in answer to [this](http://answers.opencv.org/question/96817/how-to-create-mask-from-an-image-in-opencv/) question. You can do this, for example, by this way (insert code below after Your `Imgproc.findContours()` call instead of `for (int contourIdx = ...`:

```
// create Mat for mask
Mat mask =  new Mat(new Size(srcMat.cols(), srcMat.rows() ), CvType.CV_8UC1);
mask.setTo(new Scalar(0.0));

// create Scalar for color of mask objects
Scalar white = new Scalar(255, 255, 255);

// draw contours border and fill them
Imgproc.drawContours(mask, contours, -1, white, 10);
for (MatOfPoint contour: contours) {
    Imgproc.fillPoly(mask, Arrays.asList(contour), white);
}

// create mat foe masked image
Mat masked = new Mat();

// apply mask to srcMat and set result to masked
srcMat.copyTo(masked, mask);
```

Then change `gray` mat in `Utils.matToBitmap()` call to `masked`:

```
Utils.matToBitmap(masked, b);
imgR.setImageBitmap(b);
```